# Python send automated emails through gmail

Tags: python, email, automation, gmail

I'm working with a company that uses gmail. Is there anyway I can send an automated email two or three times a day with reminders, using python? From what I've googled or seen, I've only been able to find how to email using python in general. Anyway to automate it?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Perhaps start with [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).

Comment: If you've figured out how to send email from Python code, then you've figured out how to automate it.  Can you describe the problems you had with the solutions you've found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like the only piece you're missing is something to automatically run your Python ever so often.

I'd recommend crontab. Through a terminal, you can type: `crontab -e`. From there, add an entry similar to the following:

`0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * python /absolute/path/to/my/file.py`

the "0,4,8,12,16,20" piece means it'll run the python script at midnight, 4am, 8am, 12pm, 4pm, and 8pm every day.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [good solution](http://segfault.in/2010/12/sending-gmail-from-python/) on sending mails by python through gmail.